# How to get the permission for CaaS Engine of Huawei Mobile Services(HMS)?

Tags: android, mobile, huawei-mobile-services, drone.io, huawei-developers

Would like to obtain permissions to use open APIs of Huawei CaaS Engine to share MeeTime video call which is from an flying drone.
I would try to let users to get the video streaming through MeeTime.
The code is almost ready but HwCaasServiceManager initialization function always returned error 2002 (PERMISSION_FAIL/Authentication failed) because I need permission to access CaaS Engine open APIs.
Checked Huawei official website and cannot find solution: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-Guides/virtualized-devices-calling-introduction-0000001051089010

Anyone can help for the error?
Thanks,
S

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [CssS Engine Result Code](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-Guides/error-code-0000001050785972), value **2002** means Authentication failed. You are advised to [configure app information in AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-Guides/virtualized-devices-calling-config-agc-0000001051143066) and then use the service.

The process is as follows:

1. Before you get started, please register as a HUAWEI developer and complete identity verification on [HUAWEI Developers](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en).
2. [Create an AppGallery Connect Project](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started#createproject) and [Add an App to the Project](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started#createapp).
3. Generate a Signing Certificate Fingerprint.

a. Open the command-line interface (CLI) using the **cmd** command, and run the **cd** command to go to the directory where **keytool.exe** is located. In the following example, the JDK is installed in the **Program Files** folder in drive C.

```
C:\>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin>
```

b. Run **keytool -list -v -keystore**  and respond as prompted. In the command,  indicates the absolute path to the app's signing certificate.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\TestApp.jks
```

c. Obtain the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint.

4. Configure the Signing Certificate Fingerprint.

a. Sign in to [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) and click **My projects**.

b. Find your app project, and click the desired app name.

c. Go to **Project settings** > **General information**. In the **App information** area, click an icon next to **SHA-256 certificate fingerprint**, and enter the obtained SHA-256 certificate fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

The current CaaS opens four seed capabilities:
**virtual device audio and video calls**, **screen sharing**, **in-app calls**, and **in-app custom calls**;
Currently in-app custom calls only works in China region currently. It will be available out of China regions in 2021 H2.

More info. regarding CaaS integration on HMS platform is [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-Guides/error-code-0000001050785972). and Caas Engien result code is [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-Guides/error-code-0000001050785972).

Answer (score 0):

See the [`HwCaasServiceCallBack`](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-References/vir-devices-calling-hwcaasservicecallback-0000001051009105) error codes:

> `2002`: Authentication failed. (Check whether you have applied for the required permission for calling the API from Huawei and whether the `appid` generated during app creation on HUAWEI Developers has been added to `AndroidManifest.xml`).

One can obtain the key fingerprint a whole lot easier with: `./gradlew signingReport`